# How to download transporter app mentioned in WWDC 2019 in order to test standalone Apple Watch app

Tags: app-store, apple-watch, testflight

I would like to use Test Flight to test a standalone Apple Watch app created with SwiftUI.

In WWDC 2019 Apple mentions that the way to do this is through a new Mac app called transporter. The link where they mention this is below.
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/301/

How can I download this transporter Mac app? I can't find this app anywhere.

I do not know how else to test a standalone Apple Watch app. There is no way to do this on App Store Connect and the only instructions that I have seen Apple give are in the above WWDC talk.

Any help resolving this issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Ryan, it seems not (yet) to be available. You should be able to submit it directly through Xcode 11 though.

Comment: It appears that I'm unable to submit an independent watch app to App Store Connect as it only allows submission of iOS, tvOS, and MacOS apps. How would I submit a standalone watch app through Xcode 11?

Comment: Then it's probably not yet ready for submission / testing. You can try to post something over at the Apple Developer forum.

Comment: Thanks Max, I'll do that. I'm sure there are some other people who would like to start testing standalone watch apps as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also stuck with this problem, I have to test watchOS 6 standalone app and just came to know that Apple hasn't released it yet.

https://www.apple.com/watchos/watchos-preview

https://www.macworld.co.uk/news/apple/apple-watch-series-5-release-date-3690229/

App store will be available in watch OS 6.

After releasing watch OS 6, hopefully Apple will add an option to upload standalone apps in iTunes.

Looks like we both have to wait till September :)

Comment: If you have an Apple Developer Account, you can test beta software of watch OS 6 right now! It's currently on my Apple Watch.   https://developer.apple.com/download/